# Как сделать вертикальную линию с помощью html и css

Tags: html, css

Изучил основы html и css, начал практиковаться в вёрстке макетов. Делаю второй проект. Не знаю как сделать такую вертикальную линию. Спасибо за помощь!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkOKi.png

Comment: Сделать можно по-разному. Приложите пример кода, где вы хотите это применить, возможно результаты Ваших попыток.

Answer (score 0):

Пример 1

```css
.items {
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 75px;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

.item+.item {
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
</div>
```

Пример 2

```css
.items {
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 75px;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  position: relative;
}

.item+.item:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 1px;
  height: 80%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ff0000 0%,#cbebff 50%,#0000ff 100%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Хорошие примеры, почему минусовать?

Answer (score 0):

С помощью тега `<hr>`

```css
.info {
  display: flex;
}

.text {
  padding: 32px;
}

.custom-hr {
  width: 2px;
  border: 0;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="info">
  <div class="text">Test</div>
  <hr class="custom-hr">
  <div class="text">Test</div>
  <hr class="custom-hr">
  <div class="text">Test</div>
  <hr class="custom-hr">
  <div class="text">Test</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Пожалуйста! Вам надо почитать про всевдоэлементы before и after.

```css
.container {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: white;
}

.template {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 50px;
  padding: 0 60px;
}

.template:not(:last-child)::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  transform: translate(50%, -50%);
  height: 100%;
  width: 3px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">
        <div class="template">
            12
        </div>
        <div class="template">
            5K
        </div>
        <div class="template">
            1K
        </div>
        <div class="template">
            4K
        </div>
    </div>
```